# How to add custom mail id in empathy

Tags: empathy, google-chat

How to add custom mail id in telepathy account manager/empathy? i.e I want to add *your-name@yourcompany.org* which was created in google apps. I want to use it as gmail id.
I tried logging in by selecting gmail account, but it results **invalid username/password**.

**My system info:** Ubuntu 12.10, Empathy 3.6.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the server to talk.google.com under advanced settings. I'm not on my Ubuntu machine, so doing this out of my head. Should point you in the right direction though.